# PyQT custom widget fixed as square

Tags: python, qt, widget, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm developing a custom widget (inheriting from QWidget) to use as a control. How can I fix the aspect-ratio of the widget to be square, but still allow it to be resized by the layout manager when both vertical and horizontal space allows?

I know that I can set the viewport of the QPainter so that it only draws in a central square area, but that still allows the user to click either side of the drawn area.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like there is no universal way to keep a widget square under all circumstances.
You must choose one:

- Make its height depend on its width:

```
class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        policy = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Preferred, QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        policy.setHeightForWidth(True)
        self.setSizePolicy(policy)
    ...
    def heightForWidth(self, width):
        return width
    ...
```

- Make its minimal width depend on its height:

```
class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Preferred, QSizePolicy.Preferred)
    ...
    def resizeEvent(self, e):
        setMinimumWidth(height())
    ...
```

Such a widget will be kept square as long as there is such a possibility.

For other cases you should indeed consider changing the viewport, as you mentioned. Mouse events shouldn't be that much of a problem, just find the center of the widget (divide dimensions by 2), find `min(width, height)` and go from there. You should be able to validate the mouse events by coordinate. It is nice to call [`QMouseEvent.accept`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qevent.html#accept), only if the event passed the validation and you used the event.

Answer (score 4):

I'd go with BlaXpirit's method, but here's an alternative that I've used before.

If you subclass the custom widget's `resiseEvent()` you can adjust the requested size to make it a square and then set the widget's size manually.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class CustomWidget(QtGui.QFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QFrame.__init__(self, parent)

        # Give the frame a border so that we can see it.
        self.setFrameStyle(1)

        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel('Test')
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        # Create a square base size of 10x10 and scale it to the new size
        # maintaining aspect ratio.
        new_size = QtCore.QSize(10, 10)
        new_size.scale(event.size(), QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
        self.resize(new_size)

class MainWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
       QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

       layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
       self.custom_widget = CustomWidget()
       layout.addWidget(self.custom_widget)
       self.setLayout(layout)


app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWidget()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```